# Did Apple remove the zooming feature from the Magic Mouse in a recent OS update?

Tags: mouse, zoom, gesture

Mac OS X has a 'zoom' action which can be used in various views in applications e.g. Photos.app when looking at a photo, zooming an entire Safari page, zooming in an NSScrollView.

This action is easily performed on a trackpad by using the 'pinch' gesture.

I cannot for the life of me, work out how to enable it for the Magic Mouse (when running Mac OS X 10.10 Yosemite).

The closest that I can get is in the 'Zoom' section of the 'Accessibility' pref pane.  This allows you to zoom the *entire screen* which is not the behaviour that I'm looking for.

You used to be able to perform the zoom action using the mouse (see this video at 1:26 - https://youtu.be/UXbwOIsXNL8?t=1m26s )

So - have Apple removed this feature?  Or is there a way to enable in-app zooming with the Magic Mouse?

Thanks

Comment: still there in Mavericks !

Comment: Is it there in the Mouse pref pane?  If so - then you've answered my question...

Comment: Yes it is. Be aware that some apps have they internal zooming actions, so the set up is not global. Try it with Preview to test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So - It appears that they did remove this feature in Yosemite.

Answer (score 5):

Hold down cmd# while scroling then the magic mouse zooms.

Comment: I don't know why this was -1 but I follow the cmd+scroll and it zooms the content.

Comment: This is a different zoom in some programs, and doesn't work in others. E.g. in Vivaldi, Macbook touchpad pinch will smoothly magnify the entire page without causing a change in layout (you can pan over the enlarged page), while zooming with cmd + magic mouse scroll will adjust the page's zoom slider widget, while still constraining the page to the window's size, causing the magnified page content to get cramped in its window.

Comment: Why adding an extra button, i feel so comformy using a mouse until the zoom.

Answer (score 1):

On Sierra i found lovely hidden options!

Hold down CONTROL button to zoom the entire screen area 
Hold down OPTION to use a zoom tool eg photoshop

Answer (score 1):

Zooming with the Magic Mouse was switched to the "Smart Zoom" functionality done by **double tapping** on the mouse with one finger. More info on gestures here: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204895

Comment: Why. Just why. :(

Comment: @thephpdev so you buy the Magic Trackpad

Answer (score 0):

If my trackpad wasn't working with gestures, I'd go to Zoom In Or Out is enabled in System Preferences->Trackpad-> Scroll & Zoom. If it is, I'd make sure Pinch With Two Fingers is selected.

Try this, but click on the Mouse pane in System Preferences.

Comment: Thanks, but there is no zoom gesture listed in the Mouse pref pane.

Comment: Try disconnecting the Magic Mouse, then reconnecting it. Also, it might be in Trackpad, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

I have the latest updates and a Magic Mouse and mine works fine, so I guess the answer would be no.

Comment: You can zoom in and out *within* an app just using the Magic Mouse (and a modifier key on the keyboard)?  i.e. not zooming the whole screen.

Answer (score 0):

In Numbers app, you can zoom with `option` + `cmd` + `scroll`.

Answer (score 0):

Zoom features in the Accessibility section of System Preferences always several alternative options for zooming.